# AWS Auto scaling terminating instance & creating 2nd instance with new root volume & IP. what is the use of auto scaling here?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

AWS Auto scaling terminating instance & creating 2nd instance with new root volume,1st instance root volume available! what is the use of auto scaling here? It just created empty instance, IP changed,rpm's,services installed not replicated to 2nd instance.

If I manually deatach attach root volume of old instance to new instance  and restore services manually then what is the use of Auto Scale?

Any way to handle this?

Comment: It sounds like you don't understand at all what auto scaling is supposed to do. What triggered the autoscaling event that caused the instance to be deleted and a new one to be created? Also you need to understand that autoscaling creates new instances from an AMI (a point in time snapshot that you specifed), not from a currently running instance. If you are making changes to a currently running instance instead of changes to that AMI, then those changes won't make it to new instances. If you don't want the old volumes of deleted instances then update that setting...

Comment: AWS Auto Scaling is a 'scale out' service, not a 'scale up' service. That means that (and I'm over-simplifying here) when traffic doubles then the Auto Scaling service doubles the number of compute instances (this is 'scale out') rather than double the size of each existing compute instance (that would be 'scale up').

Comment: You didnt tell the solution you just told all theory which I know already.

Comment: Sense of entitlement is strong in this one.

Comment: In short my question is How your newly created instance will handle traffic ? If it doesn't have any applications,configuration & services in it which were running in terminated instance. Tell me configuration to make auto scale service to copy services of previous instance to the new one . simply it create new blank instance, in which you think it is useful ?

Answer (score 0):

Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling will always scale-out by **launching a new EC2 instance** (including its own Amazon EBS boot volume) and will scale-in by **terminating an EC2 instance**. By default, EBS volumes on a terminated instance will be deleted by this can be overridden to keep the volume (but it won't be used when Auto Scaling launches a new instance).

**To pre-load software onto an Amazon EC2 instance** that is launched by Auto Scaling, there are two choices:

- **Create a fully-configured AMI** containing all desired software and configurations. When Auto Scaling launches a new instance, it will create a boot volume (and additional volumes if desired) and will automatically load the disk contents from the AMI (Amazon Machine Image). Thus, each instance will boot with a fully-configured disk. It is your responsibility to create the AMI and maintain it with the latest version of the software you want to use. Also, please note that each new instance contains exactly what was saved on the AMI -- any changes to a disk attached to an instance is *not* reflected on any other instances because they are separate disk volumes.
- **Use a startup (*User Data*) script** to configure the instance after it boots. This script can download and install software, set configurations and do anything you wish to script! The downside is that it takes a little longer for the instance to be ready because it needs to perform these startup tasks. The benefit of this method is that the software can be updated simply by starting a new volume — the script could automatically download the latest version of the software (whereas an AMI always contains the same contents unless a new AMI is created). This is a great way to upgrade systems — just throw away an old instance and start a new instance!

It is also possible to *combine* these two methods, such as having a *mostly-configured* AMI (eg with desired frameworks and security configurations) and then use a startup User Data script to finish the setup by installing the application.

Comment: Hi John, What you do if you have Database in the terminated instance with some data in another volume ? how do you get that database in 2nd instance..Manual work suggestion is not appreciated by any one, any automation can be done ?

Comment: You should not put a database on an instance that can be terminated. A database should be continually running, either on an EC2 instance outside of the Auto Scaling group, or by using an Amazon Relational Database Service (RDS) database.